# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'isdigit' with no floats in the df

Tags: python, pandas, attributeerror

I am running the below bit of code and getting the subject error; however there are no floats in the data set I'm testing with right now (there are blanks), so not sure why it's throwing that error? Even more so when there is an else statement to handle the case when item.isdigit() is not True?

```
for item in df['Vehicle Number']:
    if item.isdigit():
        if item[0] == "0":
            df['Vehicle Number'] = df['Vehicle Number'].replace([item], item[1:4])
    elif re.search(pattern, item):  
        match = re.search(pattern, item)
        idx = match.span() # determine the start/finish of the pattern
        start = idx[0]+2
        end = idx[1]
            
        if item[start] == "0":
            df['Vehicle Number'] = df['Vehicle Number'].replace([item], item[start+1:end])
        else:
            df['Vehicle Number'] = df['Vehicle Number'].replace([item], item[start:end])
```

Comment: Can you post the full error message? Also, can this be simplified? If its the `if item.isdigit():` line, then the rest of the code isn't needed for the test. It would help to show the dtype of the offending column. And`print(repr(item))` just before that line would tell us a lot more. Take the error message to heart: its a float, guaranteed. So you need to catch it in the act (the print) and figure out why its there. if the dtype is "object" then its perfectly valid to be a mix of strings and floats.

Comment: If it really is a float, then then elif/else clauses make no difference. The exception is raised  before the code ever gets there.

Comment: Assuming we get this whole float thing sorted, you may be able to simplify this code. Perhaps something as simple as `re.sub(f"({pattern})?0?(.{{4}})", "\\2", item)`. And work out the larger bug where you take a single value in Vehicle Number but then apply the change to the entirety of the column. `df['Vehicle Number'] = df['Vehicle Number'].replace([item], item[1:4])`.

Comment: Perhaps this code could boil down to `df["Vehicle Number"].replace(f"({pattern})?0?(.{{4}})", "\\2", regex=True)`. We look for an optional pattern, an optional 0, then capture 4 characters. Then replace with those 4 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By converting the 'Vehicle Number' column to strings using `.astype(str)`, you ensure that all values are treated as strings, and then you can apply string methods like `.isdigit()`

```
# Convert 'Vehicle Number' column to string
df['Vehicle Number'] = df['Vehicle Number'].astype(str)

pattern = r'\d{2}-\d{2}'  # Example pattern, change it according to your actual pattern

for item in df['Vehicle Number']:
    if item.isdigit():
        if item[0] == "0":
            df['Vehicle Number'] = df['Vehicle Number'].replace([item], item[1:4])
    elif re.search(pattern, item):  
        match = re.search(pattern, item)
        idx = match.span() # determine the start/finish of the pattern
        start = idx[0]+2
        end = idx[1]
            
        if item[start] == "0":
            df['Vehicle Number'] = df['Vehicle Number'].replace([item], item[start+1:end])
        else:
            df['Vehicle Number'] = df['Vehicle Number'].replace([item], item[start:end])
```

Comment: But isn't a float in this dataset a bug? Simply masking bugs leads to more trouble down the line.

Comment: @tdelaney, Agree with you. it's important to investigate and address the root cause rather than just masking the issue. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Re, "there are no floats in the data set" OK, but what is "the data set?" And how was the `df` dict constructed from it? "AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'isdigit'" is exactly the error message you should expect to see raised if `item` is a `float` object.

Answer (score 0):

Without the actual data causing this error it's hard to narrow down the problem. Nevertheless the method `isdigit` should be able to interpret floats, as that's the whole point of the method yet they must be in a `string` format ([python documentation for `isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit)) thus I'd recommend you cast `item` to a string (in case a single entry happens to be of say float type). I guess you should try `if str(item).isdigit():` but again without the actual entries of `df['Vehicle Number']` it's impossible to say definitively what the problem is.

Comment: It seems to me like a float in this dataset is a bug. Simply masking it by converting everything to a string hides the bug instead of fixing it.

Comment: @Solomon Slow you didn't read the whole sentence, `isdigit` should be able to check whether a floating point number is a integer or not YET it must be in a string format.

Comment: I think my previous comment was somewhat of a knee-jerk response, which was based on me having a more narrow idea of what "floating point" means than you have. I've deleted it.